# Wildfly 16.0.0.Final and ejb-client connections with security realm

Tags: java, jboss, ejb, wildfly

The Wildfly Developer Guide explains [here](https://docs.wildfly.org/16/Developer_Guide.html#setting-up-ejb-client-context-properties) how to setup an `InitialContext` using Wildfly specific properties.

The section about "Scoped EJB Client contexts" [outlines](https://docs.wildfly.org/16/Developer_Guide.html#Scoped_EJB_client_contexts) that you can pass these properties also to the `InitialContext`:

```
Properties jndiPropsL = new Properties();
jndiPropsL.setProperty(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");
jndiPropsL.setProperty("endpoint.name", "client-endpoint");
jndiPropsL.setProperty("org.jboss.ejb.client.scoped.context", "true");
jndiPropsL.setProperty("remote.connectionprovider.create.options.org.xnio.Options.SSL_ENABLED", "false");
jndiPropsL.setProperty("remote.connections", "default");
jndiPropsL.setProperty("remote.connection.default.host", jbossHost);
jndiPropsL.setProperty("remote.connection.default.port", remotingPort);
jndiPropsL.setProperty("remote.connection.default.protocol", "http-remoting");
jndiPropsL.setProperty("remote.connection.default.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOANONYMOUS", "false");
jndiPropsL.setProperty("remote.connection.default.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOPLAINTEXT", "false");
```

In contrast to that, the Wildfly Security Guide explains how to setup a "secured" EJB client connection:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.wildfly.naming.client.WildFlyInitialContextFactory");
properties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "remote+http://127.0.0.1:8080");
InitialContext context = new InitialContext(properties);
```

The credentials are passed via a `wildfly-config.xml` file.

What do I have to configure if I want the features from both documentations, i.e. a "secured" connection and a scoped context? Do I just have to provide both sets of properties and therewith set the host and port twice?

Answer (score 0):

As described in the "Wildfly Elytron Security Guide" (see [here](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY/WildFly+Elytron+Security#WildFlyElytronSecurity-ClientAuthenticationwithElytronClient)), most of the settings that have been provided previously as `remote.connection.*` property are now replaced with a dedicated section within `wildfly-config.xml`.

Only the `remote.clusters` options seems to be not supported in the new XML structure. Hence, you have to provide it as property to the `InitialContext`:

```
Properties jndiPropsL = new Properties();
jndiPropsL.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.wildfly.naming.client.WildFlyInitialContextFactory");
jndiPropsL.setProperty("remote.clusters", "ejb");
```

In contrast to older versions of the ejb-client library you only have to pass in this option if you are really using a cluster. Setting this options for a non-ha setup will result in a failed connection attempt.